# checking device Brigthness Status ios device in application background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I check device brightness of iOS device's screen if application is in background state to see if the device is in use or not? If not, is there any other solution to check if device is in running state or in idle state?

Answer (score 0):

No, if your app is backgrounded is suspended until an event wakes it up.

You can't monitor the behaviour of the phone from a backgrounded app.

Comment: Any Other Way to Check Device Is Use Or Not ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not have control over the application when its in background state. you can monitor it only when your application is in active state.